# Render new data of modal inside modal PHP, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a MySQL database of a bible that I query via php. Right now i'm in the testing phase. Below is my test file where I display a specific Chapter of a Book in a modal. The problem is that I have no idea how to essentially 'display the next chapter (or previous chapter)' when a user clicks the left or right arrow buttons on the footer of the modal.

Currently the test file shows "Genesis 12". How can I allow the user to see Genesis 13 (inside the same modal) when the user clicks the right arrow button (at the bottom)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <?php require "config.php"; ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.btn').click(function() {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
         });
      });
   </script>
   <style>
       p, span, div { font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.3rem;line-height:1.8;}
       .selverse { border-bottom:1px dotted blue;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Click</button>

     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

        <?php
            $book = "Genesis";
            $chapter = "12";
            $verse = "5";
            $v_under = "<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>";
            $v_end = "</span>";

            echo "<h4 class='modal-title'>".$book." ".$chapter."</h4>";
            echo "</div><div class='modal-body'>";

            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `asv` WHERE Book = :book AND Chapter = :chapter");
            $result->BindParam(':book',$book);
            $result->BindParam(':chapter',$chapter);
            $result->execute();
                $y = 0;
                while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $bookx = $row['Book'];
                    $chapterx = $row['Chapter'];
                    $versex = $row['Verse'];
                    $versetext=$row["VerseText"];

                    if ($versex == $verse) {
                        echo "<span style='color:rgb(57, 128, 57);font-weight:bold;'><sup style='padding-left:0.5em;'>".$versex."</sup></span><span class='selverse' id='v".$versex."'>".$versetext."</span>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<span style='color:rgb(57, 128, 57);font-weight:bold;'><sup style='padding-left:0.5em;'>".$versex."</sup></span><span id='v".$versex."'>".$versetext."</span>";
                    }
                } 
        ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style='text-align:center;'>
                <a href='javascript:;'><i  style='float:left;margin-left:1em;' class='fa fa-angle-left fa-2x'></i></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href='javascript:;'><i style='float:right;margin-right:1em;' class='fa fa-angle-right fa-2x'></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

.. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into AJAX to do something like that properly, what AJAX basically does is load content after the page has finished loading. So you can get rows out of your database without reloading the page. A very basic approach would be:

Change the href of the arrows to call the JavaScript function `loadNew();`

```
<div class="modal-footer" style='text-align:center;'>
    <a href='javascript:loadNew('previous');'><i style='float:left;margin-left:1em;' class='fa fa-angle-left fa-2x'></i></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <a href='javascript:loadNew('next');'><i style='float:right;margin-right:1em;' class='fa fa-angle-right fa-2x'></i></a>
</div>
```

Add the loadNew function to your script tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});

function loadNew(type){
    //We pass the type (previous or next row) and the current ID of the row as GET variables to the fetch.php script
    $.get("http://yoursiteurl.com/fetch.php?type="+type, function(data){
        $(".modal-header").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

Now all that's left is to create the PHP file (fetch.php), that would be something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['book'])){
    $_SESSION['book'] = "Genesis";
    $_SESSION['chapter'] = 12;
    $_SESSION['verse'] = 5;
}

if($_GET['type'] == 'next'){
    //Select the next verse, you are probably going to want to add a check to see if the chapter is available, if not go to the first chapter or something like that
    $_SESSION['chapter'] = $_SESSION['chapter'] + 1;
} else{
    $_SESSION['chapter'] = $_SESSION['chapter'] - 1;
}

$book = $_SESSION['book'];
$chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
$verse = $_SESSION['verse'];
$v_under = "<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>";
$v_end = "</span>";

echo "<h4 class='modal-title'>".$book." ".$chapter."</h4>";
echo "</div><div class='modal-body'>";

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `asv` WHERE Book = :book AND Chapter = :chapter");
$result->BindParam(':book',$book);
$result->BindParam(':chapter',$chapter);
$result->execute();
$y = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $bookx = $row['Book'];
    $chapterx = $row['Chapter'];
    $versex = $row['Verse'];
    $versetext=$row["VerseText"];

    if ($versex == $verse) {
        echo "<span style='color:rgb(57, 128, 57);font-weight:bold;'><sup style='padding-left:0.5em;'>".$versex."</sup></span><span class='selverse' id='v".$versex."'>".$versetext."</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<span style='color:rgb(57, 128, 57);font-weight:bold;'><sup style='padding-left:0.5em;'>".$versex."</sup></span><span id='v".$versex."'>".$versetext."</span>";
    }
} 
?>
```

Then save the file and edit the path `http://yoursiteurl.com/fetch.php` to the correct one.

Comment: This is perfect! One of the best, most thorough explanations I've seen on SO!

Comment: Actually there is one small problem. The line: `$(".modal-header").html(data);` places all of the verses into the modal-header and not the modal-body. How do I place the verse in the modal-body?

Comment: What you could do is replace all the html in the modal-dialog instead of modal-body or modal-header, and adjust the fetch.php file to also include the modal-header and modal-footer divs.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again. One day I will be a competent programmer :)